# How to change "Registration complete. Please check your e-mail." in wp-login.php

Tags: wp-login-form

I want to override the phrase "Registration complete. Please check your e-mail." without modifying the core code in wp-login.php

Does anyone know what the add_filter() or add_action() might look like?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

After wp-login.php figures out what error messages to display, the $errors object gets passed through the `wp_login_errors` filter:

`$errors = apply_filters( 'wp_login_errors', $errors, $redirect_to );`

When that error message is added to the list of "errors", wp-login uses the code `'registered'`, which you can use to narrow down your search.

So something like this should do it (untested, but this is the basic flow of the code):

```
add_filter( 'wp_login_errors', 'override_reg_complete_msg', 10, 2 );
function override_reg_complete_msg( $errors, $redirect_to ) {
   if( isset( $errors->errors['registered'] ) ) {
     $needle = __('Registration complete. Please check your e-mail.');
     foreach( $errors->errors['registered'] as $index => $msg ) {
       if( $msg === $needle ) {
         $errors->errors['registered'][$index] = 'Your new message';
       }
     }
   }

   return $errors;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work on WP4. For a working solution, please see this answer: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/161722/24875