# Customize the "Registration complete. Please check your e-mail." message on WP 4.0

Tags: filters, user-registration

How do we customize the "Registration complete. Please check your e-mail." message that appears when registering on WordPress 4.0? In previous versions, [Dave Ross](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120028/24875) solution worked:

```
add_filter( 'wp_login_errors', 'override_reg_complete_msg', 10, 2 );
function override_reg_complete_msg( $errors, $redirect_to ) {
   if( isset( $errors->errors['registered'] ) ) {
     $needle = __('Registration complete. Please check your e-mail.');
     foreach( $errors->errors['registered'] as $index => $msg ) {
       if( $msg === $needle ) {
         $errors->errors['registered'][$index] = 'Your new message';
       }
     }
   }

   return $errors;
}
```

Looking through `wp-login.php`, no changes have been made to the `Filter the login page errors` info. Why is the above code not working in WP 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need an alternative way, you can always hook into the `login_init` and modify the `gettext` filter:

```
add_filter( 'login_init',
    function()
    {
      add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse_161709', 99, 3 );
    }
);

function wpse_161709( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain )
{
    $old = "Registration complete. Please check your e-mail.";
    $new = "New text here";

    if ( $untranslated_text === $old )
    {         
        $translated_text = $new;
        remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

### Update — The `WP_Error` class has changed:

There seems to be a change in the definition of the `errors` property of the `WP_Errors` class:

In WordPress [version 3.9](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-includes/class-wp-error.php#L22) we got this part:

```
var $errors = array();
```

but in WordPress [version 4.0](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/class-wp-error.php#L31) it has been changed to:

```
private $error_data = array();
```

So the scope of this property has been changed from *public* to *private*.

That's the reason why you **can't modify it** directly in WordPress 4.0+.

... but you can instead use the magic `__set` and `__get` methods of the `WP_Error` class  [introduced](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22234) in WordPress 4.0.

Then your code example could be modified to:

```
add_filter( 'wp_login_errors', 'wpse_161709', 10, 2 );

function wpse_161709( $errors, $redirect_to )
{
   if( isset( $errors->errors['registered'] ) )
   {
     // Use the magic __get method to retrieve the errors array:
     $tmp = $errors->errors;   

     // What text to modify:
     $old = __('Registration complete. Please check your email.');
     $new = 'Your new message';

     // Loop through the errors messages and modify the corresponding message:
     foreach( $tmp['registered'] as $index => $msg )
     {
       if( $msg === $old )
           $tmp['registered'][$index] = $new;        
     }
     // Use the magic __set method to override the errors property:
     $errors->errors = $tmp;

     // Cleanup:
     unset( $tmp );
   }  
   return $errors;
}
```

to change this particular error message.

Here are screenshot examples:

**Before:**

[image: Before]

**After:**

[image: After]

Comment: This is lovely birgire, thank you very much! Still curious why the hooking into wp_login_errors doesn't work on WP4 but this alternative solution works just as well.

Comment: I think the other approach would work if the `errors` property of the `WP_Error` class would be *public*, but it's *private*.

Comment: I updated the answer with an example how you can modify your code snippet, using the magic *set* method (introduced in WP 4.0 as well) of the `WP_Error` class.

Comment: This is very interesting, thank you very much for the follow up. In terms of performance, or overall good practice, would it be better to hook into login_init or wp_login_errors?

Comment: Good question. Well both are unstable regarding changes to the message string. In general it might be easier to use the `gettext` filter, but we want to make sure it's not running through too many filterable texts on the site, they can be many ;-) In general I would try to use the method that's more "specific" or "less general" in solving the task, what ever that means ;-) So I think I would go with the `wp_login_errors` filter.

Comment: Just a correction to this answer. Please change the line to "Registration complete. Please check your email." (note e-mail has been changed to email). This is obviously required to make this work. Thanks! :D EDIT: I only now noticed that this was my original question haha, came here via a google search.

Comment: Thanks @ChristineCooper for the update,  please feel free to adjust the answer as needed - thanks in advance ;-) hehe yes it has happened to me too, to google my own forgotten answers - maybe there exists a phrase for that kind of re-discovery ?  ;-)

Comment: Please note that you need the `Registration complete. Please check your email.` string to be wrapped in `__()` function, without the domain argument, for this to work with different languages than English.

Comment: I also don't completely understand, why do you loop through `registered` key? it seems there's only one message under that key.

Comment: @certainlyakey thanks for your update,  I don't remember the exact specifics here but feel free to correct the answer or update it, if anything has changed since it was posted some years ago, thanks.

Comment: The `$errors['registered']` is indeed an array, thanks for the code @birgire!